# Why cant application find this libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 library? - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, installation, shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04

I have an application which depends on this library

```
libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
```

So I  compiled from source - which I obtained from [SDL image website](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)

- The compilation and install ran with no errors
- `make install` put the library here:

```txt
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
```

when I try to launch main application terminal errors out with:

> error while loading shared libraries:
>   libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

How can I get this the main application to read this lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get this the main application to read this lib?

First, you need to verify that both the application and the `libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0` are built with the same bitness (e.g. both are 32-bit, or both are 64-bit). The way to do that is to run:

```
file /path/to/app /usr/local/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
```

This should produce output similar to:

```
file -L /bin/date /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/bin/date:                       ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=1f3196df3d6126ccfa9bcb3faa3dfadf67d1b2bb, stripped
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[sha1]=882ad7aad54790e2fa6ef64ca2e6188f06bf9207, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, stripped
```

Assuming they are compatible, there are several ways to make the application use libraries from `/usr/local/lib`:

- the most local way is to add `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib` to the application link line.
- more global way (that affects all applicaitons on the system) is to edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` and add `/usr/local/lib` to it, then run `/sbin/ldconfig` as root.

P.S. on my ubuntu-14.04 system `/usr/local/lib` is *already* included in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`, so I expect that bitness mismatch is your *actual* problem here.

If the application is in fact built in 32-bit mode, you'll need to rebuild your `libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0` in 32-bit mode as well. Something like

```
configure CC='gcc -m32'
```

should do that.

Comment: very nice, yes the problem was bitness -  32bit app, 64 bit library. my compiler wont run with the `'gcc -m32'` flag but I at least know the problem and how to fix now, thanks Employed Russian!